# TypeError: file.endsWith is not a function in NextJS

Tags: javascript, next.js

I recently upgraded from nextJS v9.x.x to v12.x.x. Now I am getting following error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
TypeError: file.endsWith is not a function
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js:171:60)
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at getScripts (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js:171:40)
    at Head.getScripts (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js:367:12)
    at getDynamicScriptContent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js:553:297)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js:557:142)
    at useMaybeDeferContent (/Users/majid.hussain/workspace/hub-next/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:1251:9)
    at DeferrableHead (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js:556:28)
    at processChild (/Users/majid.hussain/workspace/hub-next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3353:14)
    at resolve (/Users/majid.hussain/workspace/hub-next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3270:5)
```

here is the transpiled code where the error originates.

[image]

and here is the output of the console.log I put in order to check for possible null values:

```
{
  sharedFiles: [
    'static/chunks/fallback/webpack.js',
    'static/chunks/fallback/main.js',
    'static/chunks/fallback/pages/_app.js'
  ],
  pageFiles: [
    'static/chunks/fallback/webpack.js',
    'static/chunks/fallback/main.js',
    'static/chunks/fallback/pages/_error.js'
  ],
  allFiles: [
    'static/chunks/fallback/webpack.js',
    'static/chunks/fallback/main.js',
    'static/chunks/fallback/pages/_app.js',
    'static/chunks/fallback/pages/_error.js'
  ]
}
```

Comment: What version of node are you running?

Comment: @evolutionxbox node version v16.3.0

Comment: Please may you share the output of `console.log(file)`?

Comment: Well yeah, i can but I wont be able to post it here in comments

Comment: No need. Please edit the question

Comment: I did that @evolutionxbox

Answer (score 0):

variable "file" either not a string or its giving "undefined".

Comment: I understand that, but what could be the possible reason. Error itself is coming from the <Head> component of `next/document`